# "shortcut app name created" show only 1 time

Tags: android

When i click on the app more time it always show "shortcut app name created" it is possible to show only 1 time ?

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent (this, GetQuoteActivity.class);      
Intent addIntent = new Intent(); 
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Get Quote"); 
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false); 
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher)); 
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

}

Comment: You can remember internally if you have already called it of course and then just don't call it a second time if you have.

Comment: No no no ... when i always run app it show this “shortcut app_name created” and i want delete it when i run app second time ...

Comment: Use shared preferences to store a boolean. Check if the boolean is true on app launch. If so, do not send the broadcast. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html